# Is it unsafe to use std::views iterators with old-school algorithms and containers?

Tags: c++, iterator, language-lawyer, c++20

I was wondering whether it is safe to use views such as `std::views::filter` or `std::views::transform` in "old-school" algorithms such as `std::accumulate`, and to construct old-school containers like `std::vector` from two iterators.

The "old-school" algorithms/containers have requirements such as *Cpp17InputIterator* for their parameters. Presumably, `std::views` iterators would have to satisfy those, otherwise the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

#### Example - IFNDR or OK?

For example:

```cpp
#include <numeric>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int arr[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    auto odds = arr | std::views::filter([](int x) { return x % 2 == 1; });
    int odd_sum = std::accumulate(std::begin(odds), std::end(odds), 0); // is this OK?
    std::cout << odd_sum << '\n';
}
```

This program compiles and prints `9` as expected, so it's seemingly okay.

#### Key issue - `std::views` iterators might not satisfy the legacy named requirements

However, there is no guarantee that all the requirements of a *Cpp17InputIterator* are satisfied by iterators of `std::views:filter`. Isn't this program technically ill-formed, no diagnostics required, unless all requirements are *coincidentally* satisfied?

To my knowledge, the `std::views` iterators only satisfy `std::xyz_iterator` because the views satisfy `std::xyz_range`.

#### Even if they look like they do, they might fail complexity requirements

Also, even if all the syntactical requirements are satisfied, I don't think there's any guarantee that the complexity requirements are satisfied:

> All the categories of iterators require only those functions that are realizable for a given category in constant time (amortized).
> Therefore, requirement tables and concept definitions for the iterators do not specify complexity.

- [[iterator.requirements.general] p13](https://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.requirements.general#13)

Does this paragraph only apply to old *Cpp17Iterator* requirements? If it did, then you could easily violate it by just making a view with a lambda that has high complexity. Such a view would have iterators that look and feel exactly like legacy iterators, but only satisfy the new `std::iterator` concept, not the old named requirements.

#### Summary

I might be wrong on this one, but my current intuition is that the above program is possibly ill-formed.
Am I misunderstanding something, or is it extremely unsafe to use `std::views` with older algorithms/standard library containers?

Keep in mind this is a [language-lawyer](/questions/tagged/language-lawyer) question, and while the answer is probably "it works in practice", I'm concerned about the technicalities.

Comment: "*If it did, then you could easily violate it by just making a view with a lambda that has high complexity.*" No, you cannot. Time complexity is relative to the size of the sequence. That is, as the sequence gets longer, does the operation take more time to complete.

Comment: @NicolBolas yes, that's exactly what I mean. You could run an `O(log n)` algorithm inside the lambda where `n` is the size of the range, and then you no longer provide amortized constant iteration.

Comment: I think standard states complexity of algorithm according to some specific operations (number of calls to predicates, number of comparaison...) protecting itself from user provided predicate/iterators.

Comment: @Jarod42 I think you may be right. In that case, the question is what "constant time (amortized)" refers to. What `n` and what operations? I suspect there is a defect.

Comment: In C++20, detecting whether an iterator meets the C++17 Iterator *Named Requirements* can be checked by the tag type of `iterator_traits<I>::iterator_category`. In your example it is `bidirectional_iterator_tag`, so it meets the template parameter requirements of `std::begin` and `std::accumulate`, so your code is fine.

Comment: Isn't this the whole reason for [P2408](https://wg21.link/p2408)'s existence? (It's already in C++23 and shipping with current MSVC, by the way)

Comment: @ildjarn good find; that seems very much related. I wasn't aware that this proposal exists, and it could most likely be used to answer this question. I've tagged this question C++20, but if language evolution in C++23 has moved past the issues, that's also a good answer.